# asp.net mvc dropdown problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

i am getting error after post, when i am using dropdown in my mvc website, the code is as follows

```
ViewData["JobSite_JobCategories1"] = new SelectList(context.JobSite_JobCategories, "Id", "Category", null);

<%= Html.DropDownList("JobCategory", ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["JobSite_JobCategories1"]))%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobCategory) %>
```

The validation is not working, and also after i catch error i fill the viewdata["JobSite_JobCategories1"] with selectlist again but still, it gives error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'JobCategory'.

Please can any one suggest me the solution to this problem, any articles, samples, links.

Comment: please provide us the code in your action and explain which post you are referring to (initial load or submit of the view?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012924/there-is-no-viewdata-item-with-the-key-tasktypes-of-type-ienumerableselectlist

Comment: and in general, you might find your answer somewhere here:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=There+is+no+ViewData+item+of+type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks correct mostly.

You are building the `SelectList` properly here:

```
ViewData["JobSite_JobCategories1"] = new SelectList(context.JobSite_JobCategories, "Id", "Category", null);
```

I am not sure why you are not just casting it to what it is here, a `SelectList`:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("JobCategory", (SelectList)(ViewData["JobSite_JobCategories1"]))%>
```

Any reason you are not using `DropDownListFor` to build it? Eg:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(m => m.JobCategory, (SelectList)(ViewData["JobSite_JobCategories1"]))%>
```

Also I posted this question a while back that might be of interest for you to read:

[Best way of implementing DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398296/best-way-of-implementing-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-2)